# Array replacement in Ruby

Tags: ruby, replace

I'm trying to do a multiple replacement in Ruby. I would do in PHP:

```
$text = "bar foo baz doom?";
$before = ["bar", "foo", "baz"];
$after = ["goto", "if", "else"];
$result = preg_replace($before, $after, $text);
// output: goto if else doom?
```

In Ruby, something like below gives me an error:

```
text = "bar foo baz doom?"
before = [/bar/, /foo/, /baz/]
after = ['goto', 'if', 'else']
result = text.gsub(before, after)
# => Can't convert Array into Regexp
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Tony, in future, consider holding off awhile before selecting an answer.  What's the rush?  Making a quick selection may discourage other, possibly better, answers from being submitted, and imo it is disrespectful to those still working on answers.  Also, by waiting you can see what others have to say about the answers.  More than once a reader has shown a selected answer to be incorrect or inefficient. Some members wait for a day or more before selecting an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Hash` with `#gsub` :-

```
text = "bar foo baz doom?"
before = ["bar", "foo", "baz"]
after = ["goto", "if", "else"]

hash = Hash[before.zip(after)]
  #=> {"bar"=>"goto", "foo"=>"if", "baz"=>"else"}
text.gsub(/\w+/) { |m| hash[m] || m }
  #=> "goto if else doom?"
```

Comment: Why are putting `;` at the end? By the way, the pry output does not look nice.

Comment: @sawa I am having dinner.. I will edit..once i will finish.. :(

Comment: Arup, no need to bolt your food; I cleaned it up for you.  Readers: note the `|| m`, rather than `hash.key?(m) ? hash[m] : m`. Nice.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you Cary. My 2 hands were blocked, so couldn't *edit*. You know my situation here. :-)

Comment: I presume that by "blocked" you mean you had food on your hands.  Consider using a fork.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a corresponding method in ruby. You can `zip` the `before` and `after` and apply every substitution separetly.Here is an example, I have used `dup` to prevent mutating the original content.

```
text = "bar foo baz doom?"
before = [/bar/, /foo/, /baz/]
after = ['goto', 'if', 'else']
result = text.dup
before.zip(after).each { |pattern, replace| result.gsub!(pattern, replace) }
result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text = "bar foo baz doom?"
before = [/bar/, /foo/, /baz/]
after = ['goto', 'if', 'else']

before.each_with_index do |reg, i|
  text.gsub!(reg, after[i])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "bar foo baz doom?"
before = [/bar/, /foo/, /baz/]
after = ['goto', 'if', 'else']
result = text.dup
before.each_index { |i| result.gsub!(before[i] ,after[i]) }
result
```

Comment: Assignment is done by reference, so you are changing the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to archive this

```
output = text.split.map { |x| before.index(x) ? after[before.index(x)] : x }.join(' ')
```

`output` contains `"goto if else doom?"`, as requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using **regex** in ruby 1.9.2 and above.

```
class String
  def preg_replace(before, after)
    gsub Regexp.union(before), Hash[before.zip(after)]
  end
end


text = "bar foo baz doom?"
before = ["bar", "foo", "baz"]
after = ["goto", "if", "else"]
text.preg_replace before, after
#=> "goto if else doom?"
```